# Converting dates as key into day names

Tags: python

I have a code below which I think should return the expected value but I don't know what's wrong with it why it didn't functioning well.

```
import calendar

weekdays = {'2019-10-21': 1,
            '2019-10-22': 2,
            '2019-10-23': 0,
            '2019-10-24': 0,
            '2019-10-25': 1,
            '2019-10-26': 0,
            '2019-10-27': 0}

days = calendar.day_name
for day, date in zip(days, weekdays.keys()):
    weekdays[day] = weekdays.pop(date)

print(weekdays)
```

actual output: `{'2019-10-25': 1, '2019-10-26': 0, '2019-10-27': 0, 'Monday': 1, 'Friday': 2, 'Saturday': 0, 'Sunday': 0}`

expected output: `{'Monday': 1, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Wednesday': 0, 'Thursday': 0, 'Friday': 1, 'Saturday': 0, 'Sunday': 0}`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add and remove items from a dictionary while you're iterating over it. Try creating a new dict for your day names instead of overwriting an existing one.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I just solved it using deepcopy.

Comment: I don't think you need to deepcopy anything at all, since `new_weekdays = dict(zip(days, weekdays.values()))` ought to do it, but whatever floats your boat :-)